Error during compilation of a Flutter app for Windows: Type 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found
I created a Flutter project, that targets Android, iOS, macOS, Linux and Windows.
It works well on both Android and iOS, but when I try to compile it on Windows 10, I got the following error:
/C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.5.0/lib/src/guid.dart(32,9): error G7D2AEF3C: Type 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.5.0/lib/src/guid.dart(32,9): error G94EA939C: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' isn't a type. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.5.0/lib/src/guid.dart(52,17): error GB1B8BC88: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.5.0/lib/src/guid.dart(56,31): error GB1B8BC88: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/C:/Users/Matt/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.5.0/lib/src/guid.dart(100,17): error GB1B8BC88: Method not found: 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView'. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: la build personnalisée de 'D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\00f4297bda59febfcdc266bbd2530f6d\flutter_windows.dll.rule;D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\785f825a0ac974305d35d5e7685e38b2\flutter_assemble.rule' s'est arrêtée. Code�1. [D:\Projects\MyProject\myproject\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

I tried flutter clean then flutter pub get but the bug remains.
Has anyone encountered this error? How can I fix that?
Thanks.

Make sure you are in 5.5.1 (5.5.1
Migrate away from UnmodifiableUint8ListView (#850))

OK so here is what I did to fix the problem:

check here that every dependency I have in my project that depends on win32 is up to date
run flutter pub upgrade win32


Follow the steps below to fix the issue. Run the following commands in your project:

flutter pub upgrade win32 then
flutter clean and finally
flutter pub get

I hope this helps. Happy coding!!

Type 'UnmodifiableUint8ListView' not found.

Check which package is still using this deprecated class, and try upgrade that

Dart 3.5.0 has a breaking change causing the issue) that deprecates the UnmodifiableUint8ListView class. This was pushed to the stable version of flutter on August 7th 2024.
Hopefully any packages that rely on this class have been upgraded or will be soon e.g. the latest versions of the win32, and archive packages have been upgraded, and libraries like tflite are working on it
The error message will tell you which package is still using the deprecated class
Upgrade all your packages using the flutter pub upgrade command

Perhaps your project was created a long time ago, as it was for me, and it helped to solve the problem by updating packages to modern versions with the command
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions


This works for me:

flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade


Incase the above solutions did not work and you are in a rush, try these 3 steps:
flutter pub cache clean
flutter channel stable
flutter pub get


This is what worked for me to fix the same issue, but running on Android.
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter run

Original:
https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_cli/issues/263

You can solve it by either:
flutter pub upgrade win32

or:
flutter pub upgrade


This command worked for me I hope this is useful for you
Flutter Pub Upgrade win32

And
flutter pub upgrade I used this command before but it didn't work for me for some reason I think try above command
